Не обновляется данные в Базе Данный sqilite3
Делаю телеграмм бота на aiogram 3. Пытаюсь сделать реферальную систему.
Вроде всё подключается, но я не могу обновить кол-во tixets в базе данных:
import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def user_exist(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))

    def add_user(self, user_id, referrer_id=None, tixets=None):
        with self.connection:
            if referrer_id != None:
                return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('user_id', 'referrer_id', 'tixets') VALUES (?, ?)", (user_id, referrer_id,))
            else:
                return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('user_id') VALUES (?)", (user_id,))

    def count_reeferals(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM users WHERE referrer_id= ?", (user_id,)).fetchone()[0]

    def count_tixets(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET tixets = (tixets + ?) WHERE user_id=?"), (1, user_id,)

Вот код для бота:
import config as cfg
import markups as nav
from db import Database


from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, F
from aiogram.types.web_app_info import WebAppInfo
from aiogram.filters.command import Command, CommandStart, CommandObject
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, Message
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import InlineKeyboardBuilder

bot = Bot(token=cfg.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher()
db = Database('database.db')

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def StartOpenProgramm(message: Message):
    if not db.user_exist(message.from_user.id):
        start_command = message.text
        referrer_id = str(start_command[7:])
        if str(referrer_id) != "":
            if str(referrer_id) != str(message.from_user.id):
                db.add_user(message.from_user.id, referrer_id)
                db.count_tixets(referrer_id)
                try:
                    await message.answer(referrer_id, 'По вашей ссылке зарегистрировался новый пользователь!')
                except:
                    pass
            else:
                await message.answer(f'Нельзя регистрироваться по собственной реферальной ссылке!')
        else:
            db.add_user(message.from_user.id)

    await message.answer(f'Добро пожаловать {message.from_user.first_name}',
                        reply_markup=nav.mainMenu())

Не появляется кол-во tixets:


В одинарные кавычки заключается строковый литерал. То есть 'users', 'user_id' - это строки, а не названия таблиц и колонок. Переделывайте.

получается в функции def count_tixets надо поставить ковычки?

У вас, кажется, возникла путаница со скобками.
Вот как у вас:
return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET tixets = (tixets + ?) WHERE user_id=?"), (1, user_id,)

А вот как надо:
return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET tixets = (tixets + ?) WHERE user_id=?", (1, user_id))

